# os.system (old python) and arguments with parameters

Tags: python, os.system

I trying to write simple code that execute os command with parameters

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os

target = "i586"

build = os.system('/usr/bin/hsh --target="target"')
```

But it always start as /usr/bin/hsh --target=target instead of target=i586.
Also subprocess.call not working cause python too old.

Please help me.

Comment: `'"target"'` is a string containing eight characters `"target"` and not the content of the variable `target`.

Comment: Please add your version of Python to the question

Answer (score 3):

```
build = os.system('/usr/bin/hsh --target="%s"' % target)
```

or

```
build = os.system('/usr/bin/hsh --target="' + target + '"')
```

Comment: Nice.Thanks.But if i want more than one parameter i must
build = os.system('/usr/bin/hsh --target="%s" --mountpoints="%s"' % target, mountpoints) ?

Comment: yes, but put brackets around the args: str % (arg1, arg2, arg3)

Comment: for multiple arguments forming the command first is much simple to understand, `cmd = '/usr/bin/hsh --target="%s, %s, %s"' %(target1, target2, target3)` then `build = os.system(cmd)`