# Passing arguments into os.system

Tags: python, argparse, os.system

I need to execute the following command through python. rtl2gds is a tool which reads in 2 parameters: Path to a file and a module name

```
rtl2gds -rtl=/home/users/name/file.v -rtl_top=module_name -syn
```

I am reading in the path to the file and module name from the user through argparse as shown below:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Read in a file..')    
parser.add_argument('fileread', type=argparse.FileType('r'), help='Enter the file path')    
parser.add_argument('-e', help='Enter the module name', dest='module_name')    
args = parser.parse_args()    
os.system("rtl2gds -rtl=args.fileread -rtl_top=args.module_name -syn")
```

But the file path that is read into args.fileread does not get in to the os.system when I call -rtl=args.fileread. Instead, args.fileread itself is being assumed as the file name and the tool flags an error.

I am sure there is a way to read in command line arguments into os.system or some other function (may be subprocess?- but couldnt figure out how). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't use `os.system()`; `subprocess` is definitely the way to go.

Your problem though is that you expect Python to understand that you want to interpolate `args.fileread` into a string. As great as Python is, it is not able to read your mind like that!

Use string formatting instead:

```
os.system("rtl2gds -rtl={args.fileread} -rtl_top={args.module_name} -syn".format(args=args)
```

If you want to pass a filename to another command, you should *not* use the `FileType` type option! You want a filename, *not* an open file object:

```
parser.add_argument('fileread', help='Enter the file path')
```

But do use `subprocess.call()` instead of `os.system()`:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['rtl2gds', '-rtl=' + args.fileread, '-rtl_top=' + args.module_name, '-syn'])
```

If `rtl2gds` implements command line parsing properly, the `=` is optional and you can use the following call instead, avoiding string concatenation altogether:

```
subprocess.call(['rtl2gds', '-rtl', args.fileread, '-rtl_top', args.module_name, '-syn'])
```

Comment: It should be `subprocess.call([..., '-syn'` **]** `)`, otherwise it's a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Thanks; thick finger typo.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.

rtl2gds needs "rtl=". It does not work with just "rtl".
When I try the subprocess option:
subprocess.call(['rtl2gds', '-rtl=' + args.fileread, '-rtl_top=' + args.module_name, '-syn'])

I get the following error:
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'file' objects

Comment: @Nanditha: did you try that with or without a space in between? (so `rtl2gds -rtl filename`).

Comment: @Nanditha: Ah, yes, you are given an open file, not a filename. Don't use `FileType`..

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Thanks a lot, this works after deleting the FileType!

Btw, I just tried 

`os.system('rtl2gds -rtl=%s -rtl_top=%s -syn' %(fr, args.module_name))` which was in another thread:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768529/os-system-old-python-and-arguments-with-parameters?rq=1]

This works too.. (only after deleting FileType. With FileType, it errors out)

Comment: @Nanditha: Yes, that's the old-style string formatting option.

Answer (score 0):

Was trying to convert a bunch of .m4a files to .mp3 files, this python script worked for me:

```
f = os.listdir()

for file in f:

    if(file.endswith('.py')):
        continue

    lastIndex = file.rfind('.')
    name = file[0:lastIndex]
    
    filename = file.replace(' ','\\ ')
    
    name = name.replace(' ','\\ ')
    
    os.system('ffmpeg -i {0} -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 8 {1}.mp3'.format(str(filename), str(name)))
```