# passing cmd line arguments to c function from python

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a list in python :

```
data = ['0x11', '0x22', '0x33' ...... ]
```

Call the executable main.out with data as argument to the binary :

```
os.system('./main.out')
```

I want to pass this list as an argument to an executable in c

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  // need data from python here
}
```

What is the best possible way of doing this ? [apart from using ctypes]

I am looking for alternative options to do this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892355/passing-arguments-into-os-system

Comment: There is no need to use ctypes at all. It is designed for calling functions from DLLs, not for running [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)es.