# Unable to find a suitable output format for 'is' is: Invalid argument in fmmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I want to make a python script to make a video in FFmpeg. I try a lot of solutions for example  but I do not know Why I do not have permission to write. I have not any idea because ffmpeg errors are a little bit tricky

my code:

```
import os
import cv2

def calculate_quote_position(quote, max_length, video_width, video_height):
    if len(quote) > max_length:
        print("Quote is too long for the video.")
        return
    
    # Determine font size and alignment
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    font_scale = 1.0
    thickness = 2
    (text_width, text_height), _ = cv2.getTextSize(quote, font, font_scale, thickness)
    
    # Calculate position for the quote
    x = int((video_width - text_width) / 2)
    y = int((video_height + text_height) / 2)
    
    return (x, y, text_width, text_height)

def create_video_from_audio_quote_picture(music_file, quote, font, font_size, font_color, background_picture, output_file, video_duration, video_width, video_height, max_length):
    quote_position = calculate_quote_position(quote, max_length, video_width, video_height)
    if not quote_position:
        print("The quote is too long for the video.")
        return
    # Create the FFmpeg command
    command = f"ffmpeg -loop 1 -t {video_duration} -i {background_picture} -i {music_file} -vf drawtext='fontfile={font}':text={quote}:fontcolor={font_color}:fontsize={font_size}:x={quote_position[0]}:y={quote_position[1]}' -shortest -c:v libx264 -c:a aac {output_file}"

    # Execute the command
    os.system(command)

music_file = "music.mp3"
quote = "This is a quote"
font = "Raleway-Bold.ttf"
font_size = 20
font_color = "white"
background_picture = "nature.png"
output_file = r"C:\Users\Lukas\Dokumenty\python_scripts\Billionare livestyle\output.mp4"
video_duration = 30
video_width = 1920
video_height = 1080
max_length = 30

create_video_from_audio_quote_picture(music_file, quote, font, font_size, font_color, background_picture, output_file, video_duration, video_width, video_height, max_length)
```

my error:

```
Input #0, image2, from 'nature.png':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 569438 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080 [SAR 72:72 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #1, mp3, from 'music.mp3':
  Metadata:
    date            : 2020:12:15 01:00:00
    title           : Otnicka - Peaky Blinder (lyrics) | i am not outsider i'm a peaky blinder
    artist          : Jigzaw
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:02:31.78, start: 0.023021, bitrate: 128 kb/s
  Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavf
  Stream #1:1: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
    Metadata:
      comment         : Other
[NULL @ 000001575c0b0100] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'is'
is: Invalid argument
```

Comment: There is a problem with how the arguments are passed to the ffmpeg command; as is, the `quote` variable is splitting into multiple arguments to the ffmpeg command, and the ffmpeg command is treating the 2nd word in `quote` (in this case, `is`) as an argument specifying the output format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;DR

The problem is most likely unintended argument parsing (splitting on whitespace) when passing text to `os.system` -- instead use `subprocess` (either `call` or `run` as appropriate) with the intended arguments, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-do-i-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command).

---

This appears to be something where the variable

```
quote = "This is a quote"
```

is inadvertently being passed in the command to ffmpeg as separate arguments `This`, `is`, `a`, and `quote`, and ffmpeg is treating `is` as an output format specifier. Try the redefined `create_video_from_audio_quote_picture` function below, which escapes the quotes around the `drawtext` arg:

```py
def create_video_from_audio_quote_picture(
    music_file,
    quote,
    font,
    font_size,
    font_color,
    background_picture,
    output_file,
    video_duration,
    video_width,
    video_height,
    max_length,
):
    quote_position = calculate_quote_position(
        quote, max_length, video_width, video_height
    )
    if not quote_position:
        print("The quote is too long for the video.")
        return
    # Create the FFmpeg command
    command = f"ffmpeg -loop 1 -t {video_duration}"
    command += f" -i {background_picture} -i {music_file}"
    command += f" -vf drawtext=\"fontfile={font}:text={quote}:fontcolor={font_color}:fontsize={font_size}:x={quote_position[0]}:y={quote_position[1]}\""
    #                          ^---------------------------------- quote this part with escaped double-quotes ----------------------------------------^
    command += f" -shortest -c:v libx264 -c:a aac {output_file}"

    os.system(command)
```

---

*Note*: the same could also happen with any of the other arguments you are passing; say you instead had

```
background_picture = "a nature picture.png"
```

as your command string is constructed, that would be parsed in `os.sytem(command)` as multiple arguments `a`, `nature`, and `picture.png`.  The most correct approach here is to use `subprocess` and pass it arguments using `subprocess.call` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892355/passing-arguments-into-os-system)